# Get user from a Validator | Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

In my SF2 project I use a `CongeValidator` class, which contains a `if` that calls a function from the service `CongesService` like that :

```
if (!$this->congeService->RTTCheck($conge)) {}
```

The function called looks like that :

```
public function RTTCheck($conge, $user){
    // $user         = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    $nbJoursConge = $this->getNombreJoursPoses($conge->getCngDateDebut(), $conge->getCngDateFin(), $conge->getCngDateDebutDemi(), $conge->getCngDateFinDemi(), $user);
    $restants     = $this->RTT_restants($user);
    if(fmod($restants, 0.5)==0)
        if($nbJoursConge-floor($restants) >= 0) return true;
    return false;
}
```

As you can see, my problem is that I need to retrieve the user (the current one, could also be as a parameter) to use that function. 
But this function is never called in a Controller, only in the Validator :/ So I have no idea on how to get <s>away with murder</s> the user properly.

Do you have any idea how I can manage that ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to inject the securityContext or the TokenStorage (depending on you symfony version) in your service.

Then you can call your user like this

`$context->getToken()->getUser()`

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I have the 2.6.5 version. Will try that right now and I will come back with my thoughts